# change iframe content

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

this is what it looks like:

```
<iframe id="uploads" name="uploads" src="/uploads/sinisa/" frameborder="yes" scrolling="no" onload="setTimeout(autoResize('uploads'),10)">
</iframe>
```

it points to directory and retrieves files in list view. i need to remove/change line "index of /uploads/sinisa" and "Parent directory".
i've managed to read iframe content with:

```
parent.document.getElementsByName('uploads')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML
```

but don't know what to do next. website i am talking about is [here](http://skolarasta.site88.net/).

p.s. also i am wondering how to change iframe link's styling

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could get the value of the `ul` element instead of the `body` element, as this has the content I assume you are after.

```
parent.document.getElementsByName('uploads')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].innerHTML
```

Note this will get all the `<li>` elements but not the parent `ul` itself, so you would need to create opening and closing `<ul></ul>` elements.